# javascript multidimensionnal array - concat second row values from first row criteria

Tags: javascript, arrays, concatenation

I need some help to concat values of 2nd row of a multidimensional array, from values of the first row.

An exemple will be more explicit:

```
var array = [
  [3, 7, 4, 7, 3, 1, 9, 3],
  ["a", "f", "c", "x", "t", "b", "e", "w"]
];
```

There are 5 different values in the first row (1,3,4,7,9) and I want to create 5 new variables like this:

```
var1 = "b"; //value 1 of the first row
var2 = "atw"; //value 3 of the first row
var3 = "c"; //value 4 of the first row
var4 = "fx" //value 7 of the first row
var5 = "e"; //value 9 of the first row
```

Thank you very much!

Comment: you'll be hard pressed getting it like `var1 =` etc

Answer (score 2):

As creating a dynamic number of variables isn't really viable, i recommend reducing the array into a single object, where keys are values from first array, and values are concatenated strings from the second array.

```js
const array = [
  [3, 7, 4, 7, 3, 1, 9, 3],
  ["a", "f", "c", "x", "t", "b", "e", "w"]
];

const result = array[0].reduce((result, elem, index) => {
  if (!result[elem]) result[elem] = "";
  result[elem] += array[1][index];
  return result; 
}, {});

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 2):

You could reduce the first array and group the second array based using the index

```js
const array = [
  [3, 7, 4, 7, 3, 1, 9, 3],
  ["a", "f", "c", "x", "t", "b", "e", "w"]
];

const [numbers, chars] = array;

const group = numbers.reduce((acc, n, i) => {
  acc[n] = acc[n] || ''
  acc[n] += chars[i]
  return acc;
}, {})

console.log(group)
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's one way you can get var1 = ... etc

```js
var array = [
  [3, 7, 4, 7, 3, 1, 9, 3],
  ["a", "f", "c", "x", "t", "b", "e", "w"]
];
function magicFunction(index) {
  return array[1].filter((_, i) => array[0][i] === index).join('');
}
let var1 = magicFunction(1);
let var2 = magicFunction(3);
let var3 = magicFunction(4);
let var4 = magicFunction(7);
let var5 = magicFunction(9);

console.log(var1, var2, var3, var4, var5);
```

Answer (score 0):

Three lines needed.

```js
const array = [
  [3, 7, 4, 7, 3, 1, 9, 3],
  ["a", "f", "c", "x", "t", "b", "e", "w"]
];

var o = {};
array[0].forEach((i,ind)=>o[i]=(o[i]?o[i]+array[1][ind]:""+array[1][ind]));
var [var1,var2,var3,var4,var5]=Object.values(o);
console.log({var1,var2,var3,var4,var5});
```

Comment: I think this is closest to your requirements. I don't know why I received no upvotes, unlike the others. :(